# break when writing outside allocated memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Using c++ I have a variable that is unexpectedly changing, this could be because I am writing outside allocated memory. The solutions that I have seen are to follow the variable and find that rare place where it should not change, but this is a very slow solution.
Is there any way to configure Visual studio debug mode to break when writing outside allocated memory?

Comment: Is it possible to implement setter/ getter for this variable?

Comment: The question you *should* have asked is "Is there a way to configure Visual studio debug mode to break whenever a given variable changes." - because that is you actual problem. The write outside allocated memory is only a wild guess to what may or may not be the source of the problem. Luckily Ari provided the correct answer.

Comment: As I said, that is a solution I already know and it is a slow one, and that's why I am making this question.

Comment: Perhaps if you had provided this information in your original question, you could save us some time. I have updated my answer with the additional info.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Data breakpoint` to catch the moment when your variable is changing. Data breakpoint could be set using `Debug\New breakpoint\New data breakpoint` menu in the Visual Studio.

**Edit:** To detect memory range violations you could use some profiling tools (e.g Bounds Checker), but this is standalone products you have to buy. Also there is a possibility to write your own memory manager to detect memory range violations. See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-memorymanager/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560858/modern-equivalent-of-boundschecker-for-visual-studio-2008) and [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/a-quick-and-simple-memory-allocator/184403440) for the details.

Comment: +1 for answering the question he *should* have asked and providing a solution to the problem instead of answering the question he actually asked :-)

Comment: not what I want, read my question again, I already know this solution

Answer (score 0):

Typically you get an Access Violation (0xC0000005) when writing outside *Windows* allocated memory. But your variable that's accidentally overwritten is definitely in allocated memory.